# Custom grid adapter is not displaying images

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to display a grid of pictures that the user can take through the app I am building.

Everything looks to be set up correctly, I am saving the respective image URIs to an ArrayList of URIs and passing that to my custom grid adapter's constructor.

From there, in my Grid Adapter class, I am setting the imageview image within the image_grid_view layout to the URI that was retrieved from the MainActivity and added to my ArrayList of URIs.

My GridAdapter class:

```
public class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    ArrayList<Uri> imagesArrList;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    Context mContext;

    public GridAdapter(Context _context, ArrayList<Uri> _images) {
        this.mContext = _context;
        this.imagesArrList = _images;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.mContext);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return imagesArrList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return imagesArrList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        NewViewHolder mViewHolder;
        Uri image = imagesArrList.get(position);

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_grid_view, parent, false);
            mViewHolder = new NewViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(mViewHolder);
        } else {
            mViewHolder = (NewViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        if (image != null) {
            mViewHolder.ivUserImage.setImageURI(image);
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    private static class NewViewHolder {
        ImageView ivUserImage;
        public NewViewHolder(View item) {
            ivUserImage = item.findViewById(R.id.userImage);
        }
    }
}
```

Main Activity:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
        int id = view.getId();
        if (id == R.id.fab) {
            IMAGE_FILE = UUID.randomUUID().toString() + ".jpg";
            File imageFileReference = createImageFile(IMAGE_FILE);
            Uri imageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "--REDACTED FOR PRIVACY---", imageFileReference);
            Log.i("FILEPROVIDERLOG", "File Path: " + imageFileReference.getAbsolutePath());
            Log.i("FILEPROVIDERLOG", "File URI: " + imageUri);
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
            ActivityCompat.startActivityForResult(this, intent, 0, null);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        File imageFileReference = getImageFileReference(IMAGE_FILE);
        Log.i("FILEPROVIDERLOG", "File Path: " + imageFileReference.getAbsolutePath());
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = 2;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFileReference.getAbsolutePath());
        iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        Uri imageURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "--REDACTED FOR PRIVACY---", imageFileReference);
        Log.i("FILEPROVIDERLOG", "File URI: " + imageURI);
        iv.setImageURI(null);
        iv.setImageURI(imageURI);
        imagesArrList.add(imageURI);
        gridView.setAdapter(new GridAdapter(this, imagesArrList));
    }

    private File createImageFile(String _fileName) {
        File imageFile = getImageFileReference(_fileName);
        try{
            imageFile.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return imageFile;
    }

    private File getImageFileReference(String _fileName) {
        File protectedStorage = getExternalFilesDir(IMAGE_FOLDER);
        return new File(protectedStorage, _fileName);
    }

}
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance for taking the time to read and/or respond to my question!

Comment: I see you displayed the picked image in **iv** right? Does the image appear there, also add a log to see the size of your grid

Comment: @MouaadAbdelghafourAITALI The image does not appear there. I'm assuming you mean within my layout on the left hand side? I will add a log to check the size. Thank you for the tip!

Comment: first pick an image and display it on `ImageView`, if it's not appear, then make sure the storage permission is granted

Comment: So I have loaded a placeholder image and it looks like it loads just fine. Using an image from my drawable folder. Also, uri permissions are enabled.